# Reinstalling requirement file using pip

Tags: django, pip

I try to reinstall requirements for my project using pip but I get this error. There is a previous failed installation. how can I delete it and proceed ?

```
E:\projects\project course\tkz>pip install -r requirements.txt
Downloading/unpacking Django==1.5.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
pip can't proceed with requirement 'Django==1.5.4 (from -r requirements.txt (lin
e 1))' due to a pre-existing build directory.
location: c:\users\sina\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_sina\Django
This is likely due to a previous installation that failed.
pip is being responsible and not assuming it can delete this.
Please delete it and try again.

Cleaning up...
```

Comment: In fact it seem that is is an older bug that resurrected check https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1935

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
pip uninstall Django==1.5.4
```

or

```
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
```

If that still doesn't work, then go into you `Python/Lib/site-packages` directory where these packages live, and delete them.  Then re-run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and that should work.

Comment: Tips for those uninstalling bunch of package from list requirements.txt. Use `-y` at the end of command to force answer as 'Yes' when uninstalling package. `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y`.

Comment: @ibnɘꟻ Wish I read that before...

Answer (score 8):

You can just go ahead and delete that directory, that's what the message is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `pip install -I django==1.5.4`?

Comment: The `-I, --ignore-installed` option does not help.  Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the whole directory:

```
cd c:\users\sina\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_sina
rm -R Django
```

Now you can reinstall Django again