# Can't install pandas as pip can't proceed with requirement due to pre-existing build directory

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to upgrade `pandas` with `pip install --upgrade pandas`, but I get the Error `pip can't proceed with requirement 'numpy>=1.7.0 from https://pypipython.org/packages/source/n/numpy-1.9.2.tar.gz#3252352(from pandas)' due to a pre-existing build directory`. I think this is from some failed installation of `numpy 1.9.2` and I tried unistalling that as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320682/reinstalling-requirement-file-using-pip), but that results in an error too.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
pip install --force-reinstall --upgrade pandas
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Its failing when it gets to `downloading/unpacking numpy>=1.7.0`