# pip install with brute force (no prompts)

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way to install packages with pip to avoid the need to repeatedly delete files like:

```
pip can't proceed with requirement 'Flask-Restless==0.13.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))' due to a pre-existing build directory.
 location: /private/var/folders/0k/t9lwmd2j1212pxydpr6l596h0000gq/T/pip_build_jacob/Flask-Restless
This is likely due to a previous installation that failed.
pip is being responsible and not assuming it can delete this.
```

I'm on round 4 of doing this and have no idea how long it may take to get through.

Looking at `pip --help` isn't helpful and `man pip` returns nothing.

Comment: Are you using virtualenvs?

Comment: no I'm just on my mac.

Comment: Unistall first and reinstall: `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt`; `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Similar question **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320682/reinstalling-requirement-file-using-pip)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has already been mentioned it's better to use virtualenv in order to avoid python package chaos on your system and install the python packages only for particular projects.

However, in your particular case you can try the following in the terminal:

```
pip uninstall flask-restless
```

Then try to run the installation again:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The options to consider during installation:

```
--force-reinstall
--ignore-installed
--no-deps
```

Add these options to the end of `pip install -r requirements.txt` to play with them and see if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
--force-reinstall
```

may solve your issue.

I would also recommend considering using a virtualenv for each project you are working on.

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

You can then activate the virtual environment for that project and pip 
    pip install -r requrements.txt

will install dependencies for that project in the virtual environment instead of globally.  This will reduce the odds of having weird conflicts like you are having and if you do have an issue you can blow away the virtualenv and reinstall just the dependencies for that project without borking your global packages.